# Jquery .each delay issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, each, delay

I'm trying to do something with JavaScript and experimenting some issues.

Here goes my Html code :

```
<div class="views-row"></div>
<div class="views-row"></div>
<div class="views-row"></div>
<div class="views-row"></div>
```

In JavaScript I try to add a class to each div with a delay and I'm not able to do this. Here go my JS

```
$('.views-row').each(function(){
            $(this).addClass("test").delay(1000);
});
```

I don't know what's wrong, does anyone knows ?

Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: @Shree i don't think so. That is different question and this is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's `delay()` is mainly for animations, use `setTimeout` instead

```
$('.views-row').each(function(index, elem){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(elem).addClass("test");
    }, index * 1000);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/kc21uu7p/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `setTimeout` with `index` argument of `.each`. [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) will pass the `this` value to the target function.

Try this:

```js
$('.views-row').each(function(index) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(this).addClass("test");
  }.bind(this), index * 1000);
});
```

```css
.test {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="views-row">Test</div>
<div class="views-row">Test</div>
<div class="views-row">Test</div>
<div class="views-row">Test</div>
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/sxL1znou/)